# What is the inside of a nut called?

Tags: language, nuts

My 3-year-old and I were sharing our traditional mix of Christmas nuts. He's getting pretty good at cracking them open by himself, and wanted to know what the part he eats is called. Anyone have an authoritative answer?

[image: Christmas nuts, from Wikipedia]

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32206/kernel-vs-core and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39578/why-the-meat-in-sweetmeat

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've always heard the "meat" of the nut, or "[nutmeat](http://www.yourdictionary.com/nutmeat)". Alternate terms include "kernel" or "seed" or, well, "nut".

If you were to ask a botanist, the edible part is the [embryo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryo) and the [endosperm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endosperm), though it varies depending on which type of [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed) you're referring to. Also, for a few seeds—not sure if any of them are called nuts—we eat the seed coat as well (e.g., beans).

Comment: Meat of the nut or "nutmeat" is correct - http://www.yourdictionary.com/nutmeat

Comment: @JacobG interestingly enough, that also validates "Kernel"

Comment: I would have said kernel. Nutmeat sounds a bit archaic.

Comment: Anyone else giggle at the term nutmeat or am I just being really immature?

Comment: @Jay those are not mutually exclusive options, you know ;)

Comment: Seed, kernel, and often nut are the entire thing, including the shell. I've always heard 'meat' as the culinary term; I'm going to edit to add in the biology names.

Answer (score -5):

Iv actually always known the inside of a peanut named the mouse, I don’t believe anybody that calls it a embryo. This part of the nut is definitely called a mouse.